# Restore truncated table from online server

Tags: mysql, database, hosting, truncate

I accidentally truncated my table from online server and I wasn't able to back up it. Please anyone help me  on what should I do.

Comment: learn from the experience, backups save jobs. Nothing else is significantly viable.

Answer (score 0):

Most viable, least work:

- From a backup

  - Check again if you have one
  - Ask your hoster if [they do backups](https://support.hostgator.com/articles/backup-policy-do-you-provide-backups); their default configuration for some setups might include a backup that you are unaware of, e.g. a database backup for wordpress or a file backup if you have a vm

Viable in some situations, little work if applicable:

- From [binary logs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-log.html). Check if they are enabled (maybe as part of your hosters default configuration, also maybe only the hoster can access them, so you may need to ask them). They contain the most recent changes to your database, and, if you are lucky, "recent" might be long enough to include everything

Less viable, more work:

- Try to recover from related data, e.g. history tables, other related tables or log files (e.g. the [mysql general query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html) or log files that your application created); you can try to analyze them to figure out what should be in your table

Least viable, most work, most expensive:

- In theory, since the data is still stored on the harddrive until it is overwritten by new data, you can try to recover the data, similar to tools that find lost blocks or deleted files on your harddrive

  - You need to stop any activity on your harddrive to increase probability of success. This will depend on your configuration and setup. E.g., in shared hosting, freed diskspace might be overwritten by other users beyond you control, on the other hand, if you are using innodb and disabled [innodb_file_per_table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table), the data is stored in a single file (and the disk space is not freed), so stopping your mysql server should prevent any remaining recoverable data from being overwritten.
  - While there are [some tools](https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/02/20/how-to-recover-deleted-rows-from-an-innodb-tablespace/) to help you with that, you will likely have to pay someone to do it for you (and even then you only get back the data that hasn't been overwritten so far), so this option is most likely only viable if your data is very valuable